# preg_match return longest match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to return a series of numbers between 5 and 9 digits long. I want to be able to get the longest possible match, but unfortunately preg_match just returns the last 5 characters that match.

```
$string = "foo 123456";
if (preg_match("/.*(\d{5,9}).*/", $string, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
};
```

will yield results

```
Array
(
[0] => foo 123456
[1] => 23456
)
```

Comment: Just remove `.*` from your pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only the numbers, you can just remove the `.*` from the pattern:

```
$string = "foo 123456";
if (preg_match("/\d{5,9}/", $string, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
};
```

Note that if the input string is `"123456789012"`, then the code will return `123456789` (which is a substring of a longer sequence of digits).

If you don't want to match a sequence of number that is part of a longer sequence of number, then you must add some look-around:

```
preg_match("/(?<!\d)\d{5,9}(?!\d)/", $string, $match)
```

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/jHbRqL)

`(?<!\d)` checks that there is no digit in front of the sequence of digits. `(?<!pattern)` is *zero-width negative look-behind*, which means that without consuming text, it checks that looking behind from the current position, there is no match for the pattern.

`(?!\d)` checks that there is no digit after the sequence of digits. `(?!pattern)` is *zero-width negative look-ahead*, which means that without consuming text, it checks that looking ahead from the current position, there is no match for the pattern.

Comment: Out of both preg_match expressions the former worked and for its brevity I chose your answer. I would like to exclude any series of digits longer than 9 characters but I couldn't get your second expression to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "local" non-greedy like `.*?`

```
<?php
$string = "foo 123456 bar"; // work with "foo 123456", "123456", etc.
if (preg_match("/.*?(\d{5,9}).*/", $string, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
};
```

result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo 123456 bar
    [1] => 123456
)
```

For more informations : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification