# preg_match() return the longest match

Tags: php, regex, sqlite, preg-match

> Disclaimer: Unless I'm not seeing, this is not the same as described in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598243/preg-match-return-longest-match) and I'll need some time to fully explain the situation.

---

A very long time ago I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663368/custom-regexp-function-to-be-used-in-a-sqlite-select-statement) about how to use the REGEXP operator in a SQLite statement. The operator is not implemented by default but it can be in runtime.

Well.. As you can see by the dates, that worked for me for years. Not entirely with the help of that topic (someone in SQLite mailing list showed me a trick) but it worked well.

Because preg_match() works differently of ereg() (as I've heard), by returning positively immediately after the first match, I took an additional precaution before populate that SQLite database by sorting the REGEXES (I'm sure this is not the right plural form) from the longest (more specific) to the shortest (more generic).

Not a big deal, just a simple uasort() using strlen().

Considering a fictional movie management catalog with two URLs like `management/actors` and `management/actors/add`, this sorting trick saved me from having false-positives while accessing the first URL and have SQLite responding with the second *resultset* only because both of them have the same immutable part `management/actors`

This is the current implementation:

```
$this -> dbh
      -> sqliteCreateFunction(

            'REGEXP',

            function( $r, $s ) {

                return ( preg_match( sprintf( '@^%s$@i', $r ), $s ) != 0 );
            },

            2
);
```

Being **$this -> dbh** the class property with the PDO instance used.

The situation now is different because this sorting trick did not consider one possibility: Two routes where the most generic is also the longest route. For example: `management/actors/add` and `management/actors/overview`.

Conceptually, the second route is more generic because it refers to a simple dashboard listing all the actors and should go to the bottom. In fact it's just an alias for `management/actors`.

And the second route is more specific because it routes the form responsible to add a new record and thus should go to the top

These routes are analyzed from PHP doc comments spread around Controller classes like this:

```
/**
 * Overview
 *
 * !Route    GET,    management/actors
 * !Route    GET,    management/actors/overview
 */
final public function overview() {}

/**
 * Add
 *
 * !Route    GET,    management/actors/add
 */
final public function add() {}
```

And comes in this order:

```
management/actors
management/actors/overview
management/actors/add
```

Because I need to identify the Action method they're structurd in different array indexes with the class method name as key:

```
Array(

    'overview' => array(

        [0] => management/actors
        [1] => management/actors/overview
    ),

    'add' => array(
        [0] => 'management/actors/add'
    )
)
```

Like I said the sorting works and can make this structure become:

```
Array(

    'overview' => array(

        [0] => management/actors/overview
        [1] => management/actors
    ),

    'add' => array(
        [0] => 'management/actors/add'
    )
)
```

But the whole component fails to work because of preg_match() implementation of SQLite REGEX operator.

So far, the only way, I managed to workaround this issue was to develop the Controller classes like this:

```
/**
 * Add
 *
 * !Route    GET,    management/projects/add
 */
final public function add() {}

/**
 * Overview
 *
 * !Route    GET,    management/projects
 * !Route    GET,    management/projects/overview
 */
final public function overview() {}
```

I mean, in the reverse order.

Fine! All applications in a certain way have their own oddities and I could live with that but, perhaps, in the future, someone else may open this code and give it some maintenance and may not be aware of this limitation.

That said (finally) I wish to know if there is a way to increase preg_match()'s gluttony and make it not stop in the first positive occurrence and match the longest possible like ereg does, or at least I think it does, I've never saw it in action.

Or an alternative solution, of course :p

As requested in comments, some examples of the REGEXES, listed in the order they're inserted in the SQLite database (after sorting):

```
management/projects/overview\b(.*?)
management/projects/add\b(.*?)
management/projects\b(.*?)
```

They're very simple REGEXES. They match mainly the Request URI. In the end of the REGEX I have only a border to distinguish the fixed string text from the variable part that *might* exists (like Xdebug profiling GET argument)

Comment: PCRE and ERE have different specification on what to return as a match when a pattern can have multiple matches starting from the same index. I don't think there is a flag in PCRE to change the behavior. Can you post your regex? The problem might be solved by rewriting your regex.

Comment: Why lazy quantifier `(.*?)`? The engine will just simply match empty string and be done. I think `(.*)` should solve your problem.

Comment: Perhaps. I almost always prefer the lazy quantifiers to not match more than I need. In this particular case doesn't matter and I surely will test its performance with it, but right nnow this is a minor issue.